# Error executing function in PHP

Tags: php, queue

I am no0b in PHP, I have a problem running some functions in php. I will try to be as clear for me to understand.
**I have 2 functions:**
 1. Create_repor1.
 2. Create_report2.

Both functions perform different operations and order must always run one and then the other. These functions deal with a lot of information from SAP q ue is stored in my MySQL DB. And my problem is that when you are running the first function occurs a problem and fails to execute the second function.

What comes to my mind is wing being executed when the first function and this fails, I want to begin to run and the second end and the first return to where the error was generated.

```
function insert_data
         take array_sap
         limit = cout(array_sap)

while array_sap > = limit
      #Begin implementing where we were.
      run function_1(array_sap) #If here an error that runs through to 'function_2'.
      run function_2(array_sap) #If everything ran well to continue again with 'function_1'.
end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Because you don't elaborate on what the `problem` is that causes the functions to fail, i doubt we'll be able to give you any real direction. Instead of showing psuedo code, why not provide the real thing

Comment: what do you mean with error? If the function1 throws an exception, you could use a try-catch block.

Comment: Can you please clarify - do you want to run the second function even if the first one generated an error, or do you want to skip the second one if the first one results in error?

Comment: 2 functions perform inserts but with different information, the error is generated runtime. I just want you if error happens in F1 to F2. And if it went well F2 to F1 pass where he stayed and finished the cycle until everything goes well.

Comment: Sorry I do not have a well structured code, I'm on an analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really possible to do this.  If an error is generated, the best you can do is catch it and run the second function at the point of failure and then try to run it again.  Like so:

```
function Create_repor1(){
  $retried = 0;
  while ($retried < 3)
  {
    $retried++;
    try
    {
       // do some stuff
       $retried = 3;
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
      $retried++;
      Delete_report2();
    }
  }
}
```

The $retried while block is necessary to have it try only once, and no more.

Answer (score 0):

Try catch is able to catch some fatal errors, prevent the script to get terminated and continue executing the other code.